# Spring MVC Session is sharing resources to all the users

Tags: spring-mvc, session-variables, sharing

I have a application with spring MVC and hibernate. My application is resource driven.

Like if user A have the access to resources items like menu items then only shown to him.

I have two users say A and B.

A have permission to search for an item and  modify its value in application only.

B have permission to search for an item and  modify its value in application as well as access to entire application.

On success full login of user i am saving user profile in to session with session.setattribute.

On every request i am authorizing the user that whether he has the access to it or not. Till here every thing is working fine.

My Problem is :

Lets say user A is loogged in... and user B is loggined via Single sign on .

Finally last logged in user resources were shown to both...? Strange that it is working fine in local...but when ever i deployed it to ist it's behaviour is odd.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have at some point a singleton bean (e.g. a `@Service`) to which you propagate the access rights after the login.

It might help if you would post the affected beans.